# Problem with the collision of the player with the ball in the game Pong

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

When the ball collides with the apex of the player's rectangle, the player begins to move along with the ball

I found no method to detect whether the collision was at the apex of the rectangle
Script Ball

```
var posicaoInit
var velocity
const SPEED= 500

func _ready():
    posicaoInit =position
    velocity=Vector2(1,-1)



func _physics_process(delta):
    var collision = move_and_collide(velocidade*delta*SPEED)
    if collision :
        velocity=velocity.bounce(collision.get_normal())
```

Script Player

```
const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -500.0




func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    velocity.x=0
    velocity.y += gravity * delta



    move_and_slide()


func _on_touch_1_pressed():
    velocity.y=JUMP_VELOCITY
```

Script Game

```
extends Node2D
var Player1Score = 0
var Player2Score = 0


func _on_wall_left_body_entered(body):
    $Boll.position = Vector2(576,324)
    Player2Score+=1
    


func _on_wall_right_body_entered(body):
    $Boll.position = Vector2(576,324)
    Player1Score+=1
    
func _process(delta):
    $Pontuacao_1.text= str(Player1Score)
    $Pontuacao_2.text =str(Player2Score)
```

Comment: This is what comes to mind: the ball is working as a moving platform for the player, does that make any sense to you? Check the `up_direction` vector of the player, and also `platform_on_leave`.